# Is this project structure valid?

Tags: java, uml

I have a dilemma: In the university we learn to create modular software (on java), but this modularity is explained using a single project with packages (a package for business, another one for DAOS and another one for the model, oh and a last package for frontend).

But in my work we use the next structure:

[image: Example]

I will try to explain:

First we create a java library project where the model (entities classes) are created in a package.

Next we create an EJB named DAOS and using the netbeans wizard we store the DAOS interfaces in the library project in another package , these interfaces are implemented in the DAOS bean.

So the next part is the business logic, we create a business EJB for each group of functions , again using the wizard we store the interface in the java library project in another package then is implemented on the business bean.

The final part (for the backend) is a bean that I have suggested: a Facade bean who will gather every method of the business beans in a single bean and this has an interface too that is created in our library project and implemented in the bean.

So the next part is call the facade module on the  web project.

But I don't know how valid or viable is this, maybe I'm doing everything wrong and I don't even know! so I want to ask your opinion about this.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the interfaces of DAOS, BusinessBeans and Facade in the model project is not a good choice.

Arguments against:

1. Data structure (entities classes), business logic (BusinessRemote, FacadeRemote) and technical logic (DAOSRemote) are mixed in one project. They are in different packages but will be delivered in one jar.

   - Reusing the data structure in other applications will lead to classes in your project that are not necessary for the new application.
2. Changes in the one of the interfaces will force a rebuild of your projects. If the facade interface needs to be changed, because of new requirements or features, you must change the interface class in your model project. This will lead to a new jar of your project that needs to be distributed.

Suggestions:

- Separating implementation and interfaces is a good approach; but go all the way. Create separate interface projects (Business, Facade, DAOS). If you are using some dependency management tool (Maven, Ivy, ...) you will add only dependencies to this interface projects. For your WAR you will include all jars separately.

Good point:

- Adding an additional interface as application facade is good. We use this approach to offer different application facades for different user roles, without mixing this role logic into our business logic.